# Android gradle resValue in task

Tags: android, gradle, resources

I need to access "**resValue**" to manipulate **strings.xml**. In the scope of **android** and like **buildTypes** it is possible to do that.

When I want to use that in a task inside the android scope, it doesnt work!

How can I use that? I do not want to manipulate the file with parsing/replacing, ... .

EDIT:

Ah ok. Before a build is started, I iterate over n-files, get keys and want to add them as a value to a resValue. Then the build has to start with that config

CODE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    // here reference to resValue possible
}

signingConfigs {

    release {
        ...
    // here reference to resValue possible
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
    // here reference to resValue possible
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
    // here reference to resValue possible

    }
}

task keysourceAll << {

    // here no reference to resValue

    def configFiles = loadConfigFiles("./configs")
    configFiles.each { File configFile ->
        if(configFile.isFile()){
            def lines = configFile.readLines()
            def configKey = lines.get(2)
            String key = getKey(configKey)

            println key
        }
    }
}
}
File[] loadConfigFiles (String rootDir) {
    file(rootDir).listFiles()
}

String getKey(String resourceLine){
    int indexStart = resourceLine.indexOf(">")
    String subString = resourceLine.subSequence(indexStart+1, resourceLine.length())
    int indexEnd = subString.indexOf("<")
    return subString.subSequence(0,indexEnd)
}
```

Greets

Luser_k

Comment: question is unclear ... could you write what you wana achive? i mean what should be the final results after build (fx: *after build all flavors should have string resources named xxx with value of flavor name*)... also you should post the gradle file to show us what is not working

Comment: Ah ok. Before a build is started, I iterate over n-files, get keys and want to add them as a value to a resValue. Then the build has to start with that config.

Comment: and "before build" you mean some gradle task?

Comment: Yes, see gradle file :).

Comment: one more thing ... do you wana add same resValuse for each flavor/buildtype ?

Comment: `applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", key, value
}` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad description.

I will load all keys in list and pick one after one.
Oh I know what you mean to say. Just pick it in buildTypes a single key.

Comment: yeap put this instead `println key`